# why cannot i close a recordset inside of a DAO transaction

Tags: database, transactions, mfc, dao

Pseudo code here:

```
RecordSetA.Open(&DB);
try
{
DB.m_WorkSpace.begintrans();
RecordSetA.Close();
DB.m_WorkSpace.Commit();
}
catch(...)
{
DB.m_WorkSpace.RollBack();
}
```

I can perform `RecordSetA.Move(),RecordSetA.Find()` inside of the transaction without any problem. But if i close this recordset inside the transaction, it gives out DAO Error when doing RollBack() or Commit(): "`You tried to commit or rollback a transaction without first beginning a transaction`".

I know in ODBC, Close() should not be performed inside a transaction(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx0e0xze.aspx), but why cannot i do so in DAO?